# Refreshing Tab with window.location on prompt()

Tags: javascript, window, prompt

I am trying to execute a tab refresh/reload when the user types **reload** in the `prompt()`. However I am getting an error around the lines of *Cannot set property of location to null* which I do not understand to what it refers to.

```
    var command = prompt("Type...");

    if(command == "reload"){
        //Reload The Tab

        //pageurl = url to refresh
        var reload = window.open(pageurl); 
        reload.location.reload();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `window.location.reload()` to reload the page.

```
 var command = prompt("Type...");
 if (command == "reload") {
     window.location.reload();
 }
```